# AdSense not appearing ONLY ON HOME PAGE, but works when I add query string

Tags: javascript, wordpress, adsense

I've been developing a website(on WordPress) and came across a very strange error.
I have AdSense ads shown, 1 on header and 1 on sidebar. It shows everywhere else, including posts, media, pages, etc. It just will not appear on my home page.

But I've noticed that if I add any sort of query string at the end of home URL, AdSense ads appear perfectly..

I've literally stayed up all night trying to solve this but I feel like I've made more mess. If anyone could please look at my website and see what the problem is, I would really appreciate it.

The website is http://catloversnation.com. You can see the ads if you go http://catloversnation.com?a or http://catloversnation.com?example=3jlfajdlsfa

Thank you so much for your help..

Comment: I can see it on the homepage on my browsers tested on both chrome and firefox, might there be a chance your homepage may be cached? try deleting your cache and reload the page

Comment: Hello codenathan, you were able to see both ads by going to catloversnation.com (without any queries)?

Comment: I don't see ads on home page on my mobile phone too (not using same wi-fi), so I'm pretty sure the error does occur..

Comment: BTW I've already tried deleting cache and reloading, probably hundreds of times.

Comment: yes although sometimes on your homepage i see 
[easy-share buttons="facebook" counters=0 native="no" facebook_text="Share On Facebook"] instead of your share on facebook button. On chrome console it says "Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. " visit this page to fix it http://developwithguru.com/solve-invalid-app-id-must-be-a-number-or-numeric-string-representing-the-application-id/

Comment: I believe you saw that while I was disabling the plug-ins. I disabled every single plug-in I had, cleared cache, but still don't see any ads. I believe the App ID is for Facebook, which has nothing to do with this problem..

Comment: So you are able to see both ads just by going to catloversnation.com without any queries?

Comment: Can someone please verify if ads can be seen on site WITHOUT THE QUERY? There are no solutions online whatsoever, and if this can't be fixed I am going to have to start a brand new website as this I can't monetize from this website.. Please help..

Comment: I cannot see them without the query, which to me would mean a caching issue either at your host or within a caching plugin that you are using.

Comment: michaelrmcneill, so if caching issue stops would it be back to normal?